# How to get 00:00; 10 September 2020 format from Date objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to get 00:00; 10 September 2020 format from Date objects?

I need to get from new Date object -> 00:00; 10 September 2020 string. How to do that?

Comment: you need to write your own formatter or use any existing date formatter library.

Comment: are you using npm? try date-fns or moment

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date is all you pretty much need

Comment: Have a look -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is unclear, [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) has a reference site explaining how to initialize a date object and how to retrieve various properties, so that you can construct your own date string.

Example:

```js
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June","July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
];
var d = new Date("09/10/2020");
var string = d.getDate()+" "+months[d.getMonth()]+" "+d.getFullYear();
console.log(string);
```

Output: 10 September 2020

Answer (score 1):

number 8 means september cause months are zero based in JS

```js
var date = new Date(2020, 8, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0);
console.log(date);
```